# proving function definition correctness in Isabelle

Tags: function, isabelle

I want to prove function definition correctness using the `function` keyword definition. Here is the definition of an addition function on the usual inductive definition of natural numbers:

```
theory FunctionDefinition
imports Main

begin

datatype natural = Zero | Succ natural

function add :: "natural => natural => natural"
where 
  "add Zero     m = m"
| "add (Succ n) m = Succ (add n m)"
```

Isabelle/JEdit shows me the following subgoals:

```
goal (4 subgoals):
 1. ⋀P x. (⋀m. x = (Zero, m) ⟹ P) ⟹ (⋀n m. x = (Succ n, m) ⟹ P) ⟹ P
 2. ⋀m ma. (Zero, m) = (Zero, ma) ⟹ m = ma
 3. ⋀m n ma. (Zero, m) = (Succ n, ma) ⟹ m = Succ (add_sumC (n, ma))
 4. ⋀n m na ma. (Succ n, m) = (Succ na, ma) ⟹ Succ (add_sumC (n, m)) = Succ (add_sumC (na, ma)) 
Auto solve_direct: ⋀m ma. (Zero, m) = (Zero, ma) ⟹ m = ma can be solved directly with
  Product_Type.Pair_inject: (?a, ?b) = (?a', ?b') ⟹ (?a = ?a' ⟹ ?b = ?b' ⟹ ?R) ⟹ ?R
```

using

```
apply (auto simp add: Product_Type.Pair_inject)
```

I get

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀P a b. (⋀m. a = Zero ∧ b = m ⟹ P) ⟹ (⋀n m. a = Succ n ∧ b = m ⟹ P) ⟹ P
```

It is not clear how to proceed. At all, is this the right way to tackle this problem?

I know that Isabelle would do this automatically if I used a `fun` definition -- I want to learn how to do this *manually* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tutorial on the `function` package](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/functions.pdf) mentions in section 3 that `fun f where ...` abbreviates

```
function (sequential) f where ...
by pat_completeness auto
termination by lexicographic_order
```

Here `pat_completeness` is a proof method from the `function` package that automates proof of completeness for patterns of datatype constructors. This is the first subgoal that you have to prove. It is recommended to apply `pat_completeness` before `auto`, because `auto` changes the syntactic structure of the goal and `pat_completeness` might not work after auto.

If you want to prove pattern completeness without `pat_completeness`, you should try to do case analysis of all function parameters, i.e., `case_tac a` in your example.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to prove termination manually, `apply (relation R)` is very useful, where `R` is a well-founded relation on the function arguments that says which of two arguments is `smaller` than the other. Usually, you will want to use `measure f` as this relation, where `f` is a function from the function argument type to `nat` and basically maps function arguments to their `size`.

Answer (score 3):

Manuel already mentioned it in his comment, but I thought a more detailed example might be helpful anyway. Here is what you can do manually:

First you specify your function as usual

```
function add :: "natural => natural => natural"
where 
  "add Zero     m = m" |
  "add (Succ n) m = Succ (add n m)"
```

and then you prove that the given patterns cover all cases by

```
  by (pat_completeness) auto
```

Afterwards you take care of termination. E.g., every `datatype` comes with a `size` function and you might note that the first argument of `add` strictly decreases in size for every recursive call. By default `function` will bundle all arguments of a function into a tuple for a termination proof, i.e., instead of *two* arguments `n` and `m`, in the termination proof you work with the *single* pair `(n, m)`. Thus if you want to tell the system that it should use the size of the *first* argument you can do this as follows:

```
termination add
  apply (relation "measure (size o fst)")
```

This will yield the remaining goals:

```
goal (2 subgoals):
 1. wf (measure (size o fst))
 2. !!n m. ((n, m), Succ n, m) : measure (size o fst)
```

That is, you have to show that the given relation is well-founded (which is trivial for `measure`s, which are always well-founded, since they are constructed by mapping arguments to natural numbers and then using less-than on the naturals as relation) *and* that for every recursive call the arguments are actually in the given relation. Both goals are easily dispatched by `simp`.

```
  apply simp
  apply simp
done
```